# Как заменить элементы не удаляя предыдущие?

Tags: javascript

Есть блок из трех элементов как заменить один на другой не удаляя предыдущий.

Попробовал `replaceWith`, `insertAdjacentHTML` ничего не помогает. Один удаляет предыдущий элемент другой  копирует еще один надо заменить их местами проста.

Используя `inserBefore` я добился изменения вниз нажатии по кнопке **down**.

Не получается написать функционал для кнопки **up**.

```js
const downElements = [...document.querySelectorAll(".down")];
downElements.forEach(downEl => {
  downEl.onclick = e => {
    const app = document.getElementById("app");
    const box = e.target.closest(".box");
    app.insertBefore(box.nextSibling, box);
  };
});
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.space-between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="box" style="background:red;width:160px">
    <h5>red box</h5>
    <div class="flex space-between">
      <button class="up">up</button>
      <button class="down">down</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box " style="background:blue;width:160px">
    <h5>blue box</h5>
    <div class="flex space-between">
      <button class="up">up</button>
      <button class="down">down</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="background:yellow;width:160px">
    <h5>yellow box</h5>
    <div class="flex space-between">
      <button class="up">up</button>
      <button class="down">down</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document#metody-vstavki

Comment: вроде бы код в сниппет работает как надо, а, я не ту кнопку проверял :) хотя с ней тоже не все гладко :)

Comment: @Grundy  К сожалению  все так и подумав понажимали там минусов =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница между кнопками `up` и `down` только в том, какой элемент перед каким надо вставить:

1. для кнопки `down` - перед текущим нужно поставить следующий `insertBefore(box.nextSibling, box)`
2. для кнопки `up` - перед предыдущим нужно поставить текущий. `insertBefore(box, box.previousSibling)`

```js
const app = document.getElementById("app");
const downElements = [...document.querySelectorAll(".down")];
downElements.forEach(downEl => {
  downEl.onclick = e => {
    const box = e.target.closest(".box");
    app.insertBefore(box.nextSibling, box);
  };
});

const upElements = [...document.querySelectorAll(".up")];
upElements.forEach(upEl => {
  upEl.onclick = e => {
    const box = e.target.closest(".box");
    app.insertBefore(box, box.previousSibling);
  };
});
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.space-between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="box" style="background:red;width:160px">
    <h5>red box</h5>
    <div class="flex space-between">
      <button class="up">up</button>
      <button class="down">down</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box " style="background:blue;width:160px">
    <h5>blue box</h5>
    <div class="flex space-between">
      <button class="up">up</button>
      <button class="down">down</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="background:yellow;width:160px">
    <h5>yellow box</h5>
    <div class="flex space-between">
      <button class="up">up</button>
      <button class="down">down</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Также стоит обратить внимание на крайние случаи, когда элемент является первым или последним, и возможно как-то специально их обработать.

Comment: Так вот оно что я не перепробовал `previousSibling`.Спасибо @Grundy (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант.

```js
const downElements = [...document.querySelectorAll(".down")];
downElements.forEach(doOnClick);

function doOnClick (downEl){
  downEl.onclick = e => {
    let box = downEl.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
    let boxNum = box.id[3];
    if (boxNum < 3) {
      boxNum++;
      var html = box.innerHTML;
      var newBox = document.getElementById("box" + boxNum);
      box.innerHTML = newBox.innerHTML;
      newBox.innerHTML = html;
    }
  }
};
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.space-between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="box1">
  <div class="box" style="background:red;width:160px">
    <h5>red box</h5>
    <div class="flex space-between">
      <button class="up">up</button>
      <button class="down">down</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id=box2>
  <div class="box " style="background:blue;width:160px">
    <h5>blue box</h5>
    <div class="flex space-between">
      <button class="up">up</button>
      <button class="down">down</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="box3">
  <div class="box" style="background:yellow;width:160px">
    <h5>yellow box</h5>
    <div class="flex space-between">
      <button class="up">up</button>
      <button class="down">down</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не работает к сожалению.